# dh_link not overwriting symlink of another package

Tags: debian, deb, debhelper

I have two packages:

- libsai-A
- libsai-B

Both of these package 'Provides' a virtual package called 'libsai', but libsai-B can 'Replace' (copy over) libsai-A. For some reason, not all the symlinks in libsai-A is getting overwritten when libsai-B is installed.

Symlinks in libsai-A .deb package:

    `./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so -> libsai-0.9.6.so.1.0.0
    ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1 -> libsai-0.9.6.so.1.0.0`

Symlinks in libsai-B .deb package:

    `./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so -> ../test/dist/libsai-B-test.so
    ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1 -> ../test/dist/libsai-B-test.so`

The first symlink (libsai-0.9.6.so) gets overwritten correctly. But the second one doesn't (libsai-0.9.6.so.1):

    `root@TB:~# ls -alt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai*
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1 -> libsai-0.9.6.so.1.0.0 <<<==     WRONG LOCATION
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1.0.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.la
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so -> ../test/dist/libsai-B-test.so

    root@TB:~# dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1
    libsai-B: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1
    root@TB:~# dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1.0.0
    libsai-A: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1.0.0`

It looks like the symlink (libsai-0.9.6.so.1) was updated to be owned by libsai-B, but the destination of that symlink is still pointing to the old location (a file owned by libsai-A).

Here is what my libsai-B.link file looks like:

    `usr/lib/test/dist/libsai-B-test.so usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so.1
    usr/lib/test/dist/libsai-B-test.so usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsai-0.9.6.so`

I'm using Autotools to trigger all the dh_helper stuff to create my package. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If your package has a `Replaces:` line it should trigger removal of the package it replaces. Does A correctly remove its symlinks when you uninstall the package? (Sorry, I somehow overlooked this detail when you originally posted your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting another package's symlink is a violation of Debian policy. If you want to replace something, you have to explicitly override it, or use a facility like alternatives.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for the info. Is there anywhere I can learn about these policies? I used this one:

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

thanks,g

Comment: That's the one, as well as the actual [policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) itself. There's probably something in the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianDevelopment) as well. Maybe check the https://debian-administration.org/ archives too; the site is no longer being updated, but they used to have some easy tutorials on various topics.